# Get address of current page in Internet Explorer from toolbar

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, mfc, toolbar

I'm trying to wrap my head around creating a toolbar (a tool band in a rebar) in MFC for Internet Explorer using COM.

Is it possible to get the address of the currently viewed page (i.e., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask in my case :-) ) from the toolbar?

If so, what should I look in to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IWebBrowser2::get_LocationURL method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752130(VS.85).aspx).